# Создание jar-файла и возможная передача параметра

Tags: java

Есть проект java. В проекте есть файл.txt. Один из классов использует данные этого файла, этому классу передаётся строка с именем файла:

```
String testFN = "test.txt";
```

Запускаю проект, всё работает. Делаю jar-файл, если полностью прописываю путь к файлу, то работает, а если так, как показано ранее, то файл не находит. А я хочу, чтобы jar-файл запускался нормально, ведь у него у самого тоже есть этот файл! Не пойму. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Может как-нибудь передавать текстовый файл в качестве параметра этому яр-файлу?

Comment: Добавьте, как вы запускаете jar-файл.

Comment: java -jar D:\Java\Project.jar

Comment: укажите еще путь к файлу test.txt внутри самого jar файла

Comment: а где именно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все зависит от того где находится ваш `test.txt`, если он находится за пределами JAR, то путь надо указывать как обычно.

Если файл упакован внутри JAR, то есть это уже рассматривается не как файл, а как ресурс, соответственно достучаться до него можно через `Class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt");`

Самый все таки лучший способ, это указывать путь к файлу через аргументы main():

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length < 1)
       System.err.println("Invalid arguments");
       return 1;
    }
    File file=new File(args[0]);
    //blah-blah
    return 0;
}
```

В этом случае никаких проблем с переносимостью кода не будет

Comment: Спасибо :) Вы мне всегда так помогаете)

Comment: Это очень плохо, хотелось бы чтобы помогал не только я. Все никак не дождусь когда здесь появится большое сообщество экспертов.